# RegEx - Value inside double square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract a value inside Double Square brackets: `[[x]]`, whilst ignoring everything else in single square brackets: `[y]`.

***NOTE:*** This RegEx is to be used in JavaScript, which as far as I understand doesn't support Looking behind

For example, take these 3 strings

```
[[32]] [Test] Lorem Ipsum
[[16]] Lorem Ipsum
[[2]] Test [BUG]
```

I want to extract: **32, 16, 2**

This is what I've tried

**Test 1:**

`\[([0-9]+)\]`

http://www.regexr.com/39sm3

Will only return the value including the inner square brackets, e.g. **[32], [16], [2]**. I could then just do another RegEx on the result, but I'd like to know how to do it once.

**Test 2:**

`\[.*?\]]`

http://www.regexr.com/39sm0

Will return the value, with the double square brackets, e.g. **[[32]], [[16]], [[2]]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
var s = '[[32]] [Test] Lorem Ipsum [[16]] Lorem Ipsum [[2]] Test [BUG]';
```

You can use a look–ahead that matches one or more digits followed by ']]' but doesn't include the ']]' in the match:

```
s.match(/\d+(?=\]\])/g)  // ["32", "16", "2"]
```

Or, if lookahead isn't available, you can use:

```
s.match(/\[\[(\d+)\]\]/g).map(function(v){return v.replace(/\[+|\]+/g,'');})
```

though if *map* is available then probably look–ahead is too. If the input is multi–line, you may need the *m* flag also.

Comment: Thanks! That does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: But won't this match patterns like `foo123]]`, with no leading double square brackets?

Comment: @torazaburo Doing some tests, yes it will, but in my case I've simply wrapped an `if` condition, to test the string for an indexOf `[[` and `]]`. Because this is for JavaScript, I can't use a Lookbehind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *capturing groups* to match substrings within patterns.

In JavaScript (the parentheses define the capturing group here):

```
var pattern = /\[\[([0-9]+)\]\]/g;
var string = "[[1]] [2] [[3]] [4] [[five]]";    
var numbers = [];

while (match = pattern.exec(string)) {
    numbers.push(match[1]); //Get capturing group 1. This would be e.g. "1"
    // NOTE: match[0] contains the entire match. e.g. "[[1]]"
}
console.log(numbers)
```

Console output: `["1", "3"]`

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html for more info on capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `/\[\[([0-9]+)\]\]/`? Assuming of course you only expect digits within the double square brackets.

```
var exp = /\[\[([0-9]+)\]\]/;
var number = exp.exec("[[293]] Test line")[1]
```

`number` should return `'293'`.

Comment: That returns `["[[32]]", "[[16]]", "[[2]]"]`, not quite what the OP wanted (as stated in the post).

Comment: The capture groups should have the correct values, though. Let me double-check.

Comment: Thanks @nhahtdh, I was careless.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
\[{2}(\d+)\]{2}
```

Telling Regex you want `{2}` `[` then some `\d` digits then another `{2}` `]`

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = 'test [[1]], test [[2]], xyz, abc, &nbsp; <p>Hi</p> test [[3]].'

let result = str.match(/\[\[(\d+)\]\]/g).map((item) => {
    return parseInt(item.replace(/[\[\]]/g, ''))
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please explain your answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

Another way of doing it with pure regex would be to use lookarounds.

```
(?<=\[\[)[0-9]+(?=\]\])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This looks great, however I need to use it in JavaScript, which sadly doesn't support Lookbehinds. I'll update the question as perhaps this wasn't obvious from the tags alone.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, sorry. That does indeed make it harder, although it looks like you've received a suitable answer. Thanks for your reply.